# how to make a checkboxes(3) checked at one click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have bunch of checkboxes,

say, if i clicked on any checkbox, i want make checked next two checkboxes also (i.e, beside two)

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="450">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/)

could anyone help me out,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Naresh: Please include some attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: In what order? Left to right? What should happen if the last one in a row is clicked? or simply the last checkbox? And what if one of the checkboxes is already checked, should it uncheck?

Comment: @palaSH actually i'm new to jquery, i googled a lot but i did't got any solutoion

Comment: Try to give them proper classes names, then select them using jQuery and then do with them whatever you want.

Comment: @NareshKamireddy Do you think programming is about googling and copying code? Programming is about learning how to use the tools and coming up with the solution yourself based on that understanding.

Comment: @NareshKamireddy, You already asked this [jQuery question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419387/swaping-the-select-box-values) `5 months ago`. Do you think you still new to jQuery? :) Its easy framework to learn

Comment: Read the documentation of DOM traversal methods in jQuery.

Comment: @ Teun Pronk Yes, exaclty i want toggle it(check/uncheck), and if next two checkboxes are there then only otherwise no need.

Comment: Thought of adding an answer , but the experts advice will be void if I do that , Will not add an answer now.. @Murali Good Observation

Comment: Please at least try to solve this issue. I don't see any trying, just requesting a solution. And make the requirements more clear, it will help you to solve the issue too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it has toggle effect as you want.

Here is the script:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).parent().nextAll("td").slice(0, 2).find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
  } 
  else {
     $(this).parent().nextAll("td").slice(0, 2).find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Here is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/21/)

Answer (score 4):

try with `nextAll()` and `eq` to select next two.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
  var obj=$(this).parent().nextAll(':eq(0),:eq(1)'); //eq(0) and (1) is the index of next two checkbox
  obj.find(':checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked)
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/17/)

this uncheck the checkbox if unchecked..

Comment: if i'm clicking anyone of 3 checked checkboxes, all three should unchecked

Answer (score 3):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().nextAll("td").slice(0, 2).find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/14/)

Comment: i want to uncheck as well

Comment: That isn't what you said in the question. Isn't it obvious how to modify my answer to do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Or try this

```
var len = 2;
var selector = 'input:checkbox'; 
$(selector).click(function(){
    var e = $(selector).index(this);   
    $(selector+':lt('+(e+len+1)+'):gt('+e+')')
       .attr('checked', 'checked');    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djCcC/5/)

Comment: you forgot to add the scripting in your fiddle

Comment: **are you serious about a click event inside a loop??** (that is unnecessary)...your selector should be `$(':checkbox').click(function(){...})`

Comment: @Aitem if i'm clicking last checkbox of a row then no need to make checked for next two checkboxes

Comment: @bipen You are right. I just use it for get index of clicked item 

it can llok like this (edit answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I have added button on each **`tr`**

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td>input[type=checkbox]').each(function (i, j) {
        if (i == 3) {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    })
})
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/8/)

Comment: This checks all the boxes in the row, not just the next two. Also, it should use `.prop()`, not `.attr()`.

Comment: i don't want to trigger with any button, it should happen while clicking checkbox itself. i mean chenge event

Comment: Now it just checks the first 3 boxes in the row, not the two boxes after the one he clicked on.

Comment: @NareshKamireddy Actually I had the thought of using checkbox attached with change event handler.  But to give a simplified example this will be easy to start.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS solution:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for(var i=0,iLen=checkboxes.length; i<iLen; i++){
    (function(i){
        checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            checkboxes[(i+1)%checkboxes.length].checked = true;
            checkboxes[(i+2)%checkboxes.length].checked = true;
        })
    }(i))
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r35vB/)

Answer (score 0):

another solution using jquery:

```
    $('input').on('click', function () {
        var count=0;
        $.each($(this).parents('tr').find('td>input[type=checkbox]'), function( index, value ) {
        if($(value).is(":checked")){
            count++;
        } else if(count > 0 && count <= 2){
            $(value).attr('checked', true);
            count++;
        }
        });
    })
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hn25/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this working script

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(obj){
       if( $(this).is(':checked')) {  
             $(this).parent().nextAll().has(":checkbox").eq(0).find(":checkbox").attr('checked','checked');
             $(this).parent().nextAll().has(":checkbox").eq(1).find(":checkbox").attr('checked','checked');

     }else{

            $(this).parent().nextAll().has(":checkbox").eq(0).find(":checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
             $(this).parent().nextAll().has(":checkbox").eq(1).find(":checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
            }                                 
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/19/)**

Comment: you can use if condition if it checked then uncheck next two check box

Answer (score 0):

A different approach. Not using the DOM, instead I'm using the array of the input elements.

**Also works for first and last element** (you didn't specify if you wanted this).

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7tR2/

```
$('input').change(function () {
    var i = $.inArray(this, $('input'));
    var n = i + 1;
    var p = i - 1;
    if (n >= $('input').length) n = 0;
    if (p < 0) p = $('input').length - 1;
    $('input').eq(n).attr("checked", $(this).attr('checked') ? true : false);
    $('input').eq(p).attr("checked", $(this).attr('checked') ? true : false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0,2).find(":checkbox").attr('checked',this.checked)
})
```

Comment: Got idea from Barmer to check the adjacent checkbox and to uncheck the already checked box from Bipen.