# restricting user to check checkboxes based on my requirement

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is in addition to previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422899/how-to-make-a-checkboxes3-checked-at-one-click-using-jquery)

I've got a bunch of checkboxes in a table, I would like to restrict the user to check the checkboxes based on following rules.

1. If user is clicking any one of the checkbox in a particular row, the we have to make next two checkboxes checked programatically (jquery) and as well as uncheck (toggle).
2. There will be Block button/checkbox, if user is clicking block button then we have to disable all checkboxes in that row, except already checked.
3. We have restrict user to check checkbox, if there is no next two checkboxes available(i.e, unchecked). This is rule exception for last checkbox in a row (User can able to check last checkbox in a row).

Here i have managed with 1 and 2 rules, but for third rule i'm not getting any idea.

**Jquery**

```
$('.grp:checkbox').change(function () {
    var obj = $(this).parent().nextAll("td").slice(0, 2);
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //$(this).removeClass('grp');
        obj.find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
        obj.find(":checkbox").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        obj.find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false);
        obj.find(":checkbox").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});


$('.block').change(function (e) {
    var obj = $(this).parent().nextAll("td");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        obj.find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        obj.find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/2JMgZ/)

if anyone giving me any suggestions, it may help full for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got my answer,
here i'm posting my answer, it my helpfull to someone.

**Jquery**

```
$('.adj :checkbox').change(function () {
    //alert('1');
    var obj = $(this).parent().nextAll("td").slice(0, 2);
    if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).hasClass("grp")) {
        //alert('2');
        if (obj.find(".grp:checkbox").hasClass("grp")) {
            var i = $(this).attr("id");
            //alert(i);
            $(this).addClass(i);
            $(this).toggleClass('grp bkd');
            obj.find(".grp:checkbox").prop('checked', true).addClass(i);
            obj.find(".grp:checkbox").prop('disabled', true).toggleClass('grp bkd');
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    } else {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).removeClass(id);
        $(this).toggleClass('grp bkd');
        obj.find("." + id + ":checkbox").prop('checked', false);
        obj.find("." + id + ":checkbox").prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('grp bkd').removeClass(id);
    }
});


$('.block').change(function (e) {
    var obj = $(this).parent().nextAll("td");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        obj.find(".grp:checkbox").prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        obj.find(".grp:checkbox").prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/2JMgZ/19/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an empty array `chked`.
2) Iterate the obj to check whether it is checked or not using `$.each()`

```
$.each(obj, function (i, j) {

    });
```

3) Push the value returned by each iteration.

```
chked.push($(j).find('input')[0].checked);
```

4) Using `$.inArray()`, check for any unchecked available

```
var isAvailable = $.inArray(false, chked);
```

this returns `-1` is any of the 2 checkbox has value `true` otherwise `0`

finally,

```
$('.grp:checkbox').change(function () {
    var obj = $(this).parent().nextAll("td").slice(0, 2);
    var chked = [];
    $.each(obj, function (i, j) {
        chked.push($(j).find('input')[0].checked);
    });

    var isAvailable = $.inArray(false, chked);
    console.log(isAvailable);
    if (chked.length != 0 && isAvailable == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //$(this).removeClass('grp');
            obj.find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
            obj.find(":checkbox").prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            obj.find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false);
            obj.find(":checkbox").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JMgZ/8/)

Comment: it is not toggeling, i mean not unchecking

Comment: still rule-1 is satisfied means check and uncheck is not woking(toggle)

Comment: @NareshKamireddy I missed a rule of yours.  check this http://jsfiddle.net/2JMgZ/12/

Comment: @NareshKamireddy I have a question, how are dealing with the checkbox before last td?

Comment: please check Rule-1, it is not satisfying

Comment: we have to restrict for before last td

Comment: @NareshKamireddy applying xnor operation will solve this barrier in rule 1

Comment: What is xnor operation and how can i?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42770/discussion-between-naresh-kamireddy-and-praveen-jeganathan)

Comment: i got my answer, thanks for your support http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/2JMgZ/19/